# Override save as behavior on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As part of a data exploration tool I'm variously drawing PNG or SVG images to a canvas. That part works fine and I understand that once drawn to canvas the image is no longer in vector format. However I'd like the user to be able to download and save the original PNG or SVG image by right-clicking on the canvas and using the standard save-as context menu. Is there any way to override the default behavior of the save-as right-click menu option?

Comment: `$('.canvas').on('contextmenu', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have been more specific. I was hoping to specifically override the save-as option not the entire context menu. Swapping the default canvas png output for my custom image.

Comment: @philippjfr: in that case, no, it's all or nothing, except for firefox briefly

Comment: @philippjfr i think no we cant change just one item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to override the default behavior of the save-as
>   right-click menu option? (I was hoping to *specifically override the
>   save-as option* not the entire context menu)

**This is (un)fortunately not doable**. As long as the right-click isn't captured by a for example `contextmenu` handler the browser will pop up an *internally* generated menu that we have no read/write access to.

You could always emulate a menu using the `contextmenu` event but since we can't read the actual content from the internally generated context menu it would impossible to get it to look identical (e.g. due to various plugin content, theme look, version changes etc.). That is of course not to say you couldn't make a replacement menu entirely.

I would suggest considering, if possible, that you simply insert the SVG as an image directly into the DOM *instead* of the canvas. This way you will be given the correct context menu by the browser (same goes for audio and video etc.). Optionally provide a button/icon/link in, for example the corner to save out the original image.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best solution is still a "save" button.

Not many users will use the contextmenu to save an image if there is a blattant <kbd>save</kbd> next to it.
For those who use the contextmenu, like most of us in here, this place is a safe place, where only our browser and us know what we're doing, with our well known features. If one day, one of these features is overridden by some website (and not just the whole menu replaced or blocked like it is on lot of websites), I'd feel trapped by the website. What else did it modified on my computer ? Is this safe place not so safe finally ? Does it know what I'd have lurk for ? If it did this to my context menu, can I trust the close button of my browser ?

---

But if you really want to do it, a workaround would be to place a transparent `<img>` with your "original" file over your canvas.

```js
ori.onload = function() {
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  // do some operation on the image
  ctx.arc(125,75,75,0,2*Math.PI)
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 250, 250);
};
```

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
}
#cont>img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
Right click the image to save the original svg version

<div id="cont">
  <canvas id="c" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
  <img id="ori" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Fiore_con_petali_arancioni_SVG.svg" />
</div>
```