# In Safari - Canvas - Right-Click save image as.. not showing in context menu

Tags: javascript, html, ios, canvas, html5-canvas

Image - RightClick in safari

[image]

Canvas - RightClick in Safari

[image]

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a question. If you want to suggest a new functionality to Safari, you should talk to Apple, not to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya, that's correct, curious wants to know anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: @tamilmani, I also had faced a similar situation. here was my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589491/how-to-support-html-right-click-context-menu-in-ipad-safari-browser

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861315/override-save-as-behavior-on-html-canvas/36863471#36863471 But they wanted the inverse. Still applicable to you: place a "save as" button in your UI directly, or set up an hack to replace your canvas with an image whose src would be set to the canvas.toDataURL() result...